# React.js: Classname CSS looks different in production build than in dev

Tags: css, reactjs

This is probably already answered somewhere so I apologize, but I couldn't find a solution for more recent versions of React and it's something I'm just very confused by.

I am running the most recent version of React and am currently creating a registration page for my app. I have a CSS file I imported with `import "./RegistrationPage.css"` and have also tried using `import registrationCSS from "./RegistrationPage.css"`. Each input also has a unique id.

I am deploying my application using AWS Amplify, and my issue is the CSS is different between my dev build and production build. On my localhost the id css are affecting my page properly but className css are partially working, but when I look at my deployed page all the className css appear different than in dev. This is a big issue since I never know what my app will truly look like till I deploy it.

I included 2 images as an example.

**Production Build**

[image]

**Dev Build**

[image]

What's the fix for this?

Thanks.

Edit: I've noticed the class css property are affecting it some if I were to remove it or change it, but that shouldn't affect it from dev to prod build I wouldn't imagine, and then it's affected even different when it's deployed (font/padding/etc shown in the images). I've also gone through all my css files several times and haven't noticed any other property that I believe could be affecting it like this. The wrapper css property seems to function differently as well.

**RegistrationPage.js**

```
<Col className="registrationWrapperInfo">
   <div>
      <InputGroup>
         <Input id="regGlow" className="registrationInputBoxes" 
           type="password" value={passwordCheck}
           placeholder="Password..." onChange={(e) => 
           setPasswordCheck(e.target.value)}/>
      </InputGroup>
   </div>
</Col>
```

**RegistrationPage.css**

```
.registrationInputBoxes {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 5px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

#regGlow:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #f069ca;
    border: 2px solid #f069ca;
}

.registrationWrapperInfo {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-height: 500px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippets ?

Comment: I've modified my post, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: What do you mean by `This is a big issue since I never know what my app will truly look like till I deploy it.` ???

Comment: I see the differences in font weight on dev and prod build, did you try to inspect this ? is using `font-weight: bolder;` safe ?

Comment: This issue is browser specific or same behaviour with all browsers ?

Comment: It's a big issue because it's resizing the shapes of my divs, adding more padding than I thought I was, pushing buttons outside my boxes, etc. It's not showing my changes while I'm developing it, and I only can see those changes or problems once I deploy it. Also, ```font-weight: bolder;``` is entirely safe, but it only shows up in my prod build, and it doesn't change the font in my dev build, when I'm actually designing it.

Comment: @JavascriptCoder Same issue on Firefox and Chrome. Haven't tested others.

Comment: Have you inspected the DOMs in the browser between development and production builds to find the diff in applied style?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes I have. Slight differences, but those that are different shouldn't be affecting it like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Reactstrap in this project, and it just now occurred to me it could be overriding my class changes, which it turns out it was. The simple fix for my question was simply to move my bootstrap import above my index.css import in my index.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. First, I had corrupt CSS files that would not allow me to build the application. Second, apparently it is difficult to compile multiple imported css files from jsx files, to fix this problem I removed all imports from all jsx files and imported them once in index.js (less and css files). Third, in the folder where you save the styles, i delete all subfolders of styles, leaving all the style files in a single folder of styles. This fixed my problem, hope that helps.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30540980)